# sh: convert: command not found on spyder

Tags: macos, python-2.7, spyder

I was working on spyder(python 2.7), and I got this ([My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK0UA.gif)). Can you explain what is the problem?

Thanks!

---

Oh sorry, here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import os

g = 10
v_o = 10
alph = np.pi/4
N_fram = 20
t_i = 0
t_f = 1.4
t_pas = (t_f - t_i)/N_fram
X_min, X_max, Y_min, Y_max = 0, 12, 0, 3

for n in range(N_fram):
    t = t_i + n*t_pas
    y = -(1/2)*g*t**2 + v_o*np.sin(alph)*t
    x = v_o*np.cos(alph)*t
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color = 'b')
    if n == (N_fram-1):
        plt.text(6, 2, "Boom !", fontsize=20)
    plt.axis([X_min, X_max, Y_min, Y_max])
    filename = 'fichierTemp'+str('%02d' %n)+'.pdf'
    plt.savefig(filename)
    print('Nplot=', n)
    plt.clf()

cmd = 'convert -delay 50 -loop 0 fichierTemp*.pdf TrajectoireBoulet.gif'
os.system(cmd)
os.system('rm fichierTemp*.pdf')
print("C'est fini !")
```

It's a gif([TrajectoireBoulet.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK0UA.gif)) but on my Mac, it's just a photo group([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP17R.jpg))

And, when I write "convert" in the terminal, I got:

```
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fftw fontconfig freetype gvc jbig jng 
jp2 jpeg lzma pangocairo png rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
Usage: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options...] file
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, they are very difficult to run.

Comment: Oh, you are looking at a GIF using **Preview** on a Mac. That doesn't work. Start **Finder** and navigate to the folder containing your GIF. Tap it ONE time briefly with the mouse, then press SPACE and it will animate correctly in Quicklook.

Comment: As regards typing `convert` you need to add all the other parameters the same ones as in your code `convert -delay 80 -loop 0 *.png animated.gif`

Comment: Or you can view your animated GIF with Safari if you start Safari and go to **File** and **Open** menu options.

Comment: Ok , but why the blue point go away?

Comment: When does it go away?

Comment: Look the difference between my gif and yours

Comment: My code is better Try comparing your code to mine... `opendiff MarksAmazingCode.py  MyCode.py`

Comment: Ok, it's good. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the full path to `convert`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/convert ...`

You can find it by running this in Terminal:

```
type convert
```

---

Also, PDF is not the best choice for the individual frames of your animation, because ImageMagick requires the external **Ghostscript** program in order to read them, so I would suggest you use `PNG` files as the intermediate format as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import os

g = 10
v_o = 10
alph = np.pi/4
N_fram = 20
t_i = 0
t_f = 1.4
t_pas = (t_f - t_i)/N_fram
X_min, X_max, Y_min, Y_max = 0, 12, 0, 3

for n in range(N_fram):
    t = t_i + n*t_pas
    y = -(1/2)*g*t**2 + v_o*np.sin(alph)*t
    x = v_o*np.cos(alph)*t
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color = 'b')
    if n == (N_fram-1):
        plt.text(6, 2, "Boom !", fontsize=20)
    plt.axis([X_min, X_max, Y_min, Y_max])
    filename = 'fichierTemp'+str('%02d' %n)+'.png'
    plt.savefig(filename)
    print('Nplot=', n)
    plt.clf()

cmd = '/full/path/to/convert -delay 50 -loop 0 fichierTemp*.png TrajectoireBoulet.gif'
os.system(cmd)
#os.system('rm fichierTemp*.pdf')
print("C'est fini !")
```

[image]

Comment: I replaced "convert" with the full path and now I get "convert: no images defined `TrajectoireBoulet.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273."

Comment: Ok, I see now. You are using an asterisk (`*`) to enumerate files and the shell normally does that for you. I'm not at a computer to check, but I think you either need to use Python's `subprocess.run()` with a shell, or use `'fichiertmp*.pdf'` and hope ImageMagick will expand the wildcard for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm new to python and don't understand how to use subprocess.run(). To be honest, it is my teacher's code and i try to understand how it works.

Comment: Try `cmd="/path/to/convert -delay 50 -loop 0 'fichierTemp*.pdf' Trajectoire.gif"`

Comment: I got "convert: no images defined `Trajectoire.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273."

Comment: Ok, you want to put some PDF files together to make an animated GIF, I assume. So your command implies you have some files called `fichierTemp01.pdf` and `fichier Temp02.pdf`, is that correct? Or are your PDF files called `fichierTemp/1.pdf` and `fichierTemp/2.pdf`? Maybe you can run `pwd; ls` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: I have not fichierTemp01.pdf or fichierTemp02.pdf and where should i run
pwd; ls ?

Comment: Do you have some PDF files? Do you want to make an animated GIF from them? Where are they relative to where you run the script? What are they called?

Comment: Yes i want to make a GIF. So i need to create some PDF files before running?

Comment: If you want to make an animated GIF you need some frames, or images. You can use PDF files or PNG files or JPEG files or whatever you want. When you have some files, you need to run `convert -delay 80  loop 0 THOSEFILES animated.gif`

Comment: I tried to create a PDF named "fichierTemp01.pdf" and i had the same issue and the PDF disapeared

Comment: Ok,I believe that I have understood the problem, I tried to remove " +'.pdf' " in filename, cmd and os.system and I got one png with 20 pictures but not a gif. I think the problem is the " +'.pdf' ". The savefig doesn't work with it but I don't know why.

Comment: Ok, I got all pictures but I didn't get a gif

Comment: Good, try running the `convert` command yourself in Terminal, outside of Python. If you have version 7 of ImageMagick, replace `convert` with `magick`

Comment: I tried with magick and I got the same issue. And when I ran convert in the terminal, I got lot of informations

Comment: Ok, I can't see the information! Please click `edit` under your original question and add the command you ran, the error messages and a listing of the PNG files in your directory.